# Solr: data file is commited, but no results returned when searching

Tags: solr

I have the latest solr running in a docker container. I import a json file with data (this file was exported in json format from an older version of solr, 3.3). I receive no errors on importing the data. The Solr admin shows that there are 764 docs as expected.

When I try to query the data (for example with `*:*`) I receive no results.

I am using the default managed-schema with added fields (which come from the old schema.xml file).

(Note: the Omeka side of things is not important here, just the Solr index and query results are needed.

I have this working in a number of other setups, but this one is not creating the index or something???

Other projects with nearly identical setup that work:

- https://github.com/scholarslab/womensbios
- https://github.com/scholarslab/twain
- https://gitlab.com/scholars-lab/latviandainas
- https://gitlab.com/scholars-lab/faulkner

All of the project files are here: https://github.com/scholarslab/falmouth

I should be getting results when I query `*:*`

Everything works as it should (Docker, the nginx proxy, Omeka, etc), so the problem is getting the results from the Solr query.

Update: 4/23/19

Querying with `http://falmouth.lib.virginia.edu/solr/falmouth/select?debugQuery=on&defType=edismax&q=id:123` or `http://falmouth.lib.virginia.edu/solr/falmouth/select?debugQuery=on&defType=edismax&df=fulltext&q=*:*` returns zero results.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

The web admin makes it seem like there is no schema loaded (not sure on the correct terms here). Screenshots below:

[Solr web admin showing documents loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUH3t.png)

[Solr web admin showing no fields available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZJ4L.png)

[Terminal showing the json post and committed without errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FflOS.png)

Comment: What does Solr return in the `parsedQuery` and `QParser` when you include `debugQuery=true` in your request? I suspect you might not have configured a default search field and/or your parser is DisMax (instead of eDisMax).

Comment: Do the documents have proper values for their uniqueKey fields? Does the Solr log show that the documents are added _and committed_? Do the `numFound` attribute show anything in the response? What does `debugQuery=true` together with the query show? Is the storage given to Solr in the docker container ephemeral (and is Solr actually able to _write to the storage_? When committing, documents are persisted to the index as physical files..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Using this query: `http://falmouth.lib.virginia.edu/solr/falmouth/select?debugQuery=on&defType=edismax&df=fulltext&q=*:*` I still get zero results. The uniqueKey field is the 'id' and the values for all of those are 4 digit numbers. In managed-schema the id field is set as type 'string'. This is the same for other similar projects that work. numFound shows 0. Solr is able to write to storage in the docker container; there are files in /opt/solr/server/solr/falmouth/data/index/.

Comment: Even if you are still getting zero results, could you update your question with the output of the parsedQuery that you got with debugQuery=on ?

Comment: Also, as a quick test, what happens if you issue a query by id? `http://falmouth.lib.virginia.edu/solr/falmouth/select?debugQuery=on&defType=edismax&q=id:123`

Comment: So there is not `debug` output even after your ran your query with `debugQuery=on`? I was expecting the output to include a node like this `"debug":{
    "rawquerystring":"id:123",
    "querystring":"id:123",
    "parsedquery":"+id:123",
    "parsedquery_toString":"+id:123",
    "explain":{},
    "QParser":"ExtendedDismaxQParser",`

Comment: @HectorCorrea That's correct. The above output is all that is returned.

Comment: I find it puzzling that even the `params` element in your response is empty!!! On a working Solr I get: `"params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "debugQuery":"on",
      "_":"1556035229633"}` How are you submitting the query?

Comment: Agreed. It's as if the schema isn't fully loaded or something (see the linked image above showing no fields available). I'm doing the query through the web admin interface. Perhaps I'll just rebuild the docker container and everything from scratch.

Comment: The "Replication" section in your screenshot should have metadata about the current index present (i.e. version). Are you sure your backend (i.e. docker) actually allows the content to be written to a storage location, and that it isn't just being quietly removed in the background? The Solr log shoudl be useful for this when the commit is being issued. Your Solr server may also be living behind a proxy that removes parameters sent directly to Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Marking as solved.

I rebuilt the docker containers from scratch, and things work now. No idea what the problem was before.